# organize postion for button and text field by css

Tags: html, css

i am trying to organize the position for these two textfield and search button, as you see they are not positioned correctly inside the `content box` div in css, i do not know which is affect who here , how can i fix the position to be in order please,

Here is my CSS code

```
body {
    background-image: url(images/stripe_4ea7f17e6b72307ec0cd17cc6d27f657.png);
    margin:50px 0px; padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
}

#content {
    border-radius: 15px; 
-moz-border-radius: 15px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 15px; 
border: 6px solid #BDF4FC;
width:50%;
height:150px;;
margin:0px auto;
    text-align:left;
    padding:15px;
    margin-top:12%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

#search {
    height: 42px;
    border: medium solid #63D1F2;

}
#button_style {
    background-image: url(images/search_button.png);
    height: 44px;
    width: 92px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 0px none #FFF;

}
```

HTML code :

```
   <div id="content">
<form action="" method="get">
<input name="" type="text" id="search" /><input type="submit" value="" id="button_style" />
</form>

</div>
```

How can i fix this ?

[image: how can i organize the position for these text field and button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:middle;` to `#button_style`.

[Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/1950925)

Comment: thanks , i've been added this code to both them and it worked :)